# How can we programmatically iterate through the Power Apps in our tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-forms

What cloud technology allows us to view all of the Power Apps (and Power Automate Flows) within our Tenant, and the properties thereof?

Specifically, I am looking to identify which Power Apps are checked out, who modified them last, etc. as well as filtering which ones are displayed.

The provided interface is rather limited in what information is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all Power apps in your tenant/environment on [Power Platform admin center](https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/).

Check below documentation for [Administrating Microsoft Power Platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/admin-documentation)

[Microsoft Power Platform Center of Excellence (CoE) Starter Kit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/guidance/coe/starter-kit) can also help you in administrating Microsoft Power Platform environments/Power apps/ Power Automate flow & governance.

---

You can also list Power apps in your tenant using Power Apps PowerShell using command:

```
Get-AdminPowerApp
```

**References**:

1. [PowerShell support for Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell)
2. [PowerShell Cmdlets for PowerApps and Flow creators and administrators](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/gdpr-admin-powershell-cmdlets/)